# why does "Email failed to send: SMTP connect() failed." still appear after having enabled less secure apps

Tags: php, phpmailer

My PHPMailer will not connect to my gmail account properly although I have enabled less secure apps and have checked my username and password several times.

I have enabled less secure apps to access my gmail account "tokens.tts@gmail.com". I have also tried to use both ssl and tls but neither seem to work. I have looked at several videos online and they all seem to mention enabling the less secure apps option but nothing else.

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    $name = "Michiel Olieslagers";
    $email = "tokens.tts@gmail.com";
    $subject = "This is just a regular email";
    $body = "I am writing this email to see whether this actually function propperly.";

    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // $mail->isSMTP();
    // $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    // $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    // $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    // $mail->Username = "tokens.tts@gmail.com";
    // $mail->Password = "hqyzZYax";
    // $mail->Port = "587";

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Username = "tokens.tts@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "********";
    $mail->Port = "465";

    $mail->isHTML(TRUE);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("micholieslagers@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    if ($mail->send()){
        echo "Email is sent";
    }
    else { echo "Email failed to send: ". $mail ->ErrorInfo; }
?>
```

I should be receiving a test email at my second account "micholieslagers@tts.edu.sg" however this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new process for GMTP SMTP has a compulsion.

Please follow the below steps to achieve the same.

Make sure you enable 2-step authentication process with your mobile number before proceeding below steps.

1. Go to google account from this link.
   [image]
2. You will see settings page with tabs on left panel. Click on security tab.
   [image]
3. Click on app passwords link. Make sure here you enabled 2-step verification.
   [image]
4. You will see select the app and device you want to generate the app password for.
   [image]
5. Select app as `mail` and select your relevant device or you can choose other at last.
   [image]
6. Click on the generate button, you will get the generated password. Copy and save it somewhere as it's one-time password otherwise you have to generate it again by creating new app password. 
   [image]
7. Now STMP configuration,

```
Host - smtp.gmail.com  
Username - your email address for which you generated the app.  
Password - Your generated password  
SMTPSecure - TLS or SSL whichever work 
Port - 465 for SSL and 587 for TLS
```

This should work as I am still using this configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately the same error is still occuring even when following your clear steps.                                             
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
 require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
 require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
 $mail->Username = "tokens.tts@gmail.com";
 $mail->Password = "****************"; 
 $mail->Port = "465";